# zend studio intellisense stopped working

Tags: intellisense, zend-studio

The intellisense feature in zend studio 7 just stopped working.

I do as usual -> Start typing, hit ctrl+space and the suggestions pop up is empty.
It just happened out of blue. No hard eclipse restarts, no crashes!

Anyone got any thoughts?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a fix myself!
http://forums.zend.com/viewtopic.php?f=59&t=5585&start=20#p19107